# How to correctly use java.util.Locale to check for Australian locale

Tags: java, locale

**Question :** How do I correctly use java.util.locale for checking a user's locale?

**Summary :** The legacy code I have uses a predefined static in Locale to check if a user is, for example, in France ...

```
if(Locale.FRANCE.equals(locale) || Locale.FRENCH.equals(locale)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I wish to add some code to check if a user is in Australia. However, Locale only has a limited set of predefined statics, and AUSTRALIA is not one of them. I appear to be able to do the following ...

```
if(new Locale("AU").equals(locale)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

However, this is inconsistent with the existing code. What is the correct way of doing it? If the first example I have given is correct, why is the predefined list of statics so limited?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. `new Locale( "AU" )` would be the language "AU" (whatever that is). You need the two argument constructor!

The `Locale.equals()` methods compares both `language`, `country` and `variant`. You should probably check like this:

```
if ( "AU".equals( locale.getCountry() ) ) { /* do stuff */ }
```

As for why the list of predefined `Locale`'s are so limited: Pass. We should probably be honored that there is anything but `en_US` at all :-)

Cheers,

Comment: Cheers Anders! Big green tick for you. The question of why the predefined locales are so limited is still up for debate though!